# Induced representation: analytic way

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $H$ a subgroup of index $r$.

Let $\rho:H\rightarrow GL(W)$ be representation of $H$ of dimension $n$.

I want to understadnd analytic definition of induced representation ${\rm Ind}_H^G\rho$. It is a representation of $G$ of dimension $n.[G:H]$.

Consider the space $V_1=\{f: f \mbox{ is a function }G\rightarrow W\}$.  This is of dimension $|G|.dim(W)$.

We want to extract a subspace  of dimension $[G:H].dim(W)$ for induced representation, and as per [encyclopedia](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Induced_representation) the space is taken as 
$$V=\{f:G\rightarrow W: f(hg)=\rho(h)f(g)\}.$$
I didn't find any intuition for defining a space for induced action of $G$ in this way! Can one explain a little?

In $f(hg)$, I was thinking it ac *take left action of $h$ on $G$ and apply $f$*, whereas $\rho(g)f(g)$ is *action of $h$ on $f(g)$*. I don't know what could be more clear way for understanding space of induced representation.

Comment: I don't have time to write a detailed answer right now, but some of the basic ideas are to note that if this is over the field $k$ then $V_1$ can also be described as $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k[G],W)$ with left $G$-action coming from the natural action on $k[G]$ and trivial action on $W$. It also has a right $H$-action coming from the right actions of $H$ on each of $k[G]$ and $W$, and $V$ is the the set of $H$-fixed points, which is $G$-invariant (since this was a right $H$-action).

Comment: Some of the intuition behind doing this is that the given space depends on the things it should, namely how $H$ acts on $W$ and how $H$ acts on $G$ (or in other words, which way $H$ sits inside $G$ as a subgroup).